# Check for key duplicates in Gridview Frontend ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

A person can have many bills.
Each bill can have many **(Item, Quantity)** entries.
My primary key is **(Bill_No,Item_Code)** .

For each **Bill_no**, I can enter a particular **Item_Code** only once.

I enter the **(Item,Quantity)** details via a Grid View as shown.

[image]

Can I validate this at the front end on **Create Indent** click so that an Item_no entered once in the gridView cannot be entered again before submit is clicked?

I have done the back end primary key validation in the Data Access Layer. It just ignores the duplicate Item_No and continues with an alert.
I want to check for duplicate **Item_code** entries row-wise via front end so no data is lost on create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //to check repeated item in the gridview
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 1)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count-1; i++)
            {
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    TextBox prevItem = (TextBox)Grid_ItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("itemCode");
                    if (prevItem.Text == itemcode && currentRow.RowIndex != rowIndex)
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation1", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Item Alredy Added, Please change the Qty if needed.')</script>");
                        txt.Text = "";
                        qtyl.Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
        SetRowData();
    }
```

put this code inside your dropdownlist onselected index change function, just before you populate the itemcode.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you'd check it against the data in your grid it would be possible that paging is enabled. Then the grid only stores the data of the current page.

Apart from that, even without paging you'll have the problem that another user could add a record at the same time with the same `Bill_no`+`Item_Code`.

So there is no other/better way than to handle the constraint exception of the database. Therefore you need to add an unique index on the combination of `Bill_no`+`Item_Code`.

Assuming SQL-Server as rdbms, you can use the `SqlException`'s [`Number` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string error = "";
try
{
    CreateIndent();
} catch (SqlException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Number)
    {
        case 2627: // Unique Index/ Primary key Violation/ Constraint Violation 
        case 2601: // Unique Index/Constraint Violation 
            error = "Bill_no and Item_Code are not unique";
            break;
        default:
            error = "Unknown SQL-Exception";
            break;
    }
}
// show error
```

**Update**

> Suppose I enter (Apple,10) , (Apple,20) and (Apple,40) as three items
>   of my gridview, my only option is to have (Apple,10) enter the
>   database and the other entries error out?
>
> string
>   unique=((TextBox)Grid_ItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).FindControl("itemCode")).‌​ToString();
>   This is how I get my data in each row. Now how do I check for
>   uniqueness?

If you insist on checking the `GridView` row by row which won't work with paging or if another user uses this page simultaneously, this should work:

```
var allItems = Grid_ItemList.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => new {
        ItemValue = ((DropDownList)r.FindControl("DdlItemName")).SelectedValue,
        ItemCode = ((TextBox) r.FindControl("itemCode")).Text.Trim()
    });
var duplicates = allItems.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
// show somewhere on the page, for example on an error-panel or label
LblError.Text = "Duplicates detected: " + 
                string.Join(",", duplicates.Select(d => d.ToString()));
```

Of course you could also use a loop to check if all combinations are unqiue.

Comment: The SQL validation is done. The constraints exist. My question is there any way I can do a validation at the grid view level? Just alert the user before submitting the entire gridview?

Comment: @divinediu: Have you read my introduction? ;-) There is no way other than asking the database. So myou could use a `CustomValidator` which will be triggered manually (`Page.Validate()`) before you save. Than each row should check the database. But it's still a race condition.

Comment: I don't mean to sound repetitive but I just need to clarify this one last time. Suppose I enter _(Apple,10)_ , _(Apple,20)_ and _(Apple,40)_ as three items of my gridview, my only option is to have _(Apple,10)_ enter the database and the other entries error out? Can't I detect 3 _Apple_ in my gridview before that? If I can, then how can I?

Comment: You could loop the rows and collect all data, then check it. Where you've got stuck? `foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView1.Rows){}`. However, once you'll enable paging you get only rows of the current page. Also, this approach does not take care of other users that are using this page simultaneously.

Comment: `string unique=((TextBox)Grid_ItemList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("itemCode")).ToString();` This is how I get my data in each row. Now how do I check for uniqueness?

Comment: @divinediu: i have edited my answer. However, it's still not easy to provide the real code since you haven't provided enough informations (f.e. the GridView markup).